# How to import files using a for loop with path names in dictionary in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, for-loop

I want to create a dictionary which has all the information needed to import files, parse dates etc. Then I want to use a for loop to import all these files. But after the for loop is finished I'm only left with the last dataset in the dictionary. As if it overwrites them.

I execute the file in the path folder so that's not a problem.

I tried creating a new dictionary where I add each import but that makes it much harder for later when I need to reference them. I want them as separate dataframes in the variable explorer.

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import AutoMinorLocator # for time series visualisation
# Import data
#PATH = r"C:\Users\sherv\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\Python-Projects\Research Project\Data"    
data = {"google":["multiTimeline.csv", "Month"], 
    "RDPI":  ["RealDisposableIncome-2004-1_Present-Mon-US(Grab-30-11-18).csv", "DATE"], 
    "CPI":   ["CPI.csv", "DATE"],
    "GDP":   ["GDP.csv", "DATE"], 
    "UE":    ["Unemployment_2004_Present_US(Grab-5-12-18).csv", "DATE"], 
    "SP500": ["S&P500.csv", "Date"], 
    "IR":    ["InterestRate_2004-1-1_Present_US(Grab-5-12-18).csv", "DATE"], 
    "PPI":   ["PPIACO.csv", "DATE"],
    "PMI":   ["ISM-MAN_PMI.csv", "Date"]}

for dataset in data.keys():
    dataset = pd.read_csv("%s" %(data[dataset][0]), index_col="%s" %(data[dataset][1]), parse_dates=["%s" %(data[dataset][1])])
    dataset = dataset.loc["2004-01-01":"2018-09-01"]
# Visualise
minor_locator = AutoMinorLocator(12)
# Investigating overall trendSS
def google_v_X(Data_col, yName, title):
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    google["Top5"].plot(ax=ax1,color='b').xaxis.set_minor_locator(minor_locator)
    ax1.set_xlabel('Date')
    ax1.set_ylabel('google (%)', color='b')
    ax1.tick_params('y', colors='b')
    plt.grid()
    ax2 = ax1.twinx()
    Data_col.plot(ax=ax2,color='r')
    ax2.set_ylabel('%s' %(yName), color='r')
    ax2.tick_params('%s' %(yName), colors='r')
    plt.title("Google vs %s trends" %(title))
# Google-CPI
google_v_X(CPI["CPI"], "CPI 1982-1985=100 (%)", "CPI")
# Google-RDPI
google_v_X(RDPI["DSPIC96"], "RDPI ($)", "RDPI")
# Google-GDP
google_v_X(GDP["GDP"], "GDP (B$)", "GDP")    
# Google-UE
google_v_X(UE["Value"], "Unemployed persons", "Unemployment")
# Google-SP500
google_v_X(SP500["Close"], "SP500", "SP500")
# Google-PPI
google_v_X(PPI["PPI"], "PPI")
# Google-PMI
google_v_X(PMI["PMI"], "PMI", "PMI")
# Google-IR
google_v_X(IR["FEDFUNDS"], "Fed Funds Rate (%)", "Interest Rate")
```

I also tried creating a function to read and parse and then use that in a loop like:

```
def importdata(key, path ,parseCol):
    key = pd.read_csv("%s" %(path), index_col="%s" %(parseCol), parse_dates=["%s" %(parseCol)])
    key = key.loc["2004-01-01":"2018-09-01"]
for dataset in data.keys():
    importdata(dataset, data[dataset][0], data[dataset][0])
```

But I get an error because it doesn't recognise the path as a string and it says its not defined.

How can I get them to not overwrite each other or how can I get python to recognise the input to the function as a string? Any help is appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The for loop is referencing the same dataset variable so each time the loop is executed the variable is replaced with the newly imported dataset. You need to store the result somewhere, whether thats as a new variable each time or in a dictionary. Try something like this:

```
googleObj = None
RDPIObj = None
CPIObj = None

data = {"google":[googleObj, "multiTimeline.csv", "Month"], 
    "RDPI":  [RDPIObj,"RealDisposableIncome-2004-1_Present-Mon-US(Grab-30-11-18).csv", "DATE"], 
    "CPI":   [CPIObj, "CPI.csv", "DATE"]}

for dataset in data.keys():
    obj = data[dataset][0]
    obj = pd.read_csv("%s" %(data[dataset][1]), index_col="%s" %(data[dataset][2]), parse_dates=["%s" %(data[dataset][2])])
    obj = dataset.loc["2004-01-01":"2018-09-01"]
```

This way you will have a local dataframe object for each of your datasets. The downside is that you have to define each variable.

Another option is making a second dictionary like you mentioned, something like this:

```
data = {"google":["multiTimeline.csv", "Month"], 
    "RDPI":  ["RealDisposableIncome-2004-1_Present-Mon-US(Grab-30-11-18).csv", "DATE"], 
    "CPI":   ["CPI.csv", "DATE"]}

output_data = {}
for dataset_key in data.keys():
    dataset = pd.read_csv("%s" %(data[dataset_key][0]), index_col="%s" %(data[dataset_key][1]), parse_dates=["%s" %(data[dataset_key][1])])
    dataset = dataset.loc["2004-01-01":"2018-09-01"]
    output_data[dataset_key] = dataset
```

Answer (score 0):

Reproducible example (however you should be very careful with using "exec"):

```
# Generating data
import os
import pandas as pd
os.chdir(r'C:\Windows\Temp')
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a',1],['b',2]], index=[0,1], columns=['col1','col2'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['c',3],['d',4]], index=[2,3], columns=['col1','col2'])

# Exporting data
df1.to_csv('df1.csv', index_label='Month')
df2.to_csv('df2.csv', index_label='DATE')

# Definition of Loading metadata
loading_metadata = {
    'df1_loaded':['df1.csv','Month'],
    'df2_loaded':['df2.csv','DATE'],
}

# Importing with accordance to loading_metadata (caution for indentation)
for dataset in loading_metadata.keys():
    print(dataset, loading_metadata[dataset][0], loading_metadata[dataset][1])
    exec(
"""
{0} = pd.read_csv('{1}', index_col='{2}').rename_axis('')
""".format(dataset, loading_metadata[dataset][0], loading_metadata[dataset][1])
)
```

Exported data (df1.csv):

```
Month,col1,col2
0,a,1
1,b,2
```

Exported data (df2.csv):

```
DATE,col1,col2
2,c,3
3,d,4
```

Loaded data:

```
df1_loaded
    col1    col2
0   a   1
1   b   2

df2_loaded
    col1    col2
2   c   3
3   d   4
```